# Maven can't compile java with a chain of stream operations

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, java-stream

like the title says, I'm having a problem when I try to compile a piece of code which has a chain of stream operations.

This doesn't happen in the IDE (tried with eclipse and IntelliJ) but when I try a 'mvn clean install' in console, it throws the following error:

```
[ERROR] .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^

[ERROR] The method collect(Collector<? super Object,A,R>) in the type Stream<Object> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<CharSequence,capture#1-of ?,String>)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Found 1 error and 0 warnings.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Test Code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamMavenTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Department> depts = initDepts();
        String unpaidReferences = depts.stream()
                .flatMap(dpto -> dpto.people.stream()
                        .filter(ppl -> ppl.lastname != null && ppl.name != null)
                        .map(ppl -> ppl.name + "|" + ppl.lastname))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
        System.out.println(unpaidReferences);
    }

    private static List<Department> initDepts() {
        List<Department> depts = new ArrayList<Department>();
        Department dep1 = new Department();
        dep1.people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        dep1.people.add(new Person("Baudouin","Quy"));
        dep1.people.add(new Person("Sigmund","Zebedaios"));
        dep1.people.add(new Person("Bernd","Edwyn"));
        depts.add(dep1);
        Department dep2 = new Department();
        dep2.people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        dep2.people.add(new Person("Olanrewaju","Jorgen"));
        dep2.people.add(new Person("Stanislovas","Adalberto"));
        dep2.people.add(new Person("Manuel","'Avshalom"));
        depts.add(dep2);
        return depts;
    }

    public static class Department{
        List<Person> people;
    }


    public static class Person{
        String name;
        String lastname;

        public Person(String name, String lastname){
            this.name = name;
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }
    }

}
```

Now, if I change the main method for this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Department> depts = initDepts();
  Stream<String> flatMap = depts.stream()
          .flatMap(dpto -> dpto.people.stream()
                  .filter(ppl -> ppl.lastname != null && ppl.name != null)
                  .map(ppl -> ppl.name + "|" + ppl.lastname));
  String unpaidReferences = flatMap
          .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
  System.out.println(unpaidReferences);
}
```

It works perfectly.

Things to keep in mind:

- Both IDE's and Maven are using same Java version.
- Java version: 1.8.0_60.
- Maven version: 3.3.3.
- Console output of main execution: Baudouin|Quy&Sigmund|Zebedaios&Bernd|Edwyn&Olanrewaju|Jorgen&Stanislovas|Adalberto&Manuel|'Avshalom

Anyone has any idea why this happens? I believe it has something to do with the flatMap and the stream inside that lambda but I'm not sure.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can't reproduce that with JDK 1.8.0_74 (using Maven 3.3.9). The first snippet compiles fine.

Comment: You'll need to post the build plugins settings from your pom before we can really help with maven issues.

Comment: @Tunaki has a good idea, a number of stream issues have been addressed in `javac` patches.  Eclipse will be using a different compiler than Maven.  Try the latest version of Java, this worked when I ran into a similar problem.

Comment: Can't repro with JDK 1.8.0_51 either.  Can you post `pom.xml`?

Comment: You might run `mvn help:effective-pom` to expand all variables, managed plugins and dependencies, and profiles to see what settings you end up with.  Check the compiler plugin settings in the output to verify you are using the compiler you think you are.

Comment: Afaik, Maven *can* use ECJ, which isn’t necessarily the same version as the ECJ of the Eclipse IDE from which you start the build process. Generally, the first thing to do when compiling from a build script shows different results, is to check which compiler (version) is actually used.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I can't post the effective pom since it's very long and has many plugins. However, I tried this with a new project with a clean pom and the problem didn't happen, so evidently, there is a problem with one of the many plugins this project has.

Answer (score 0):

try export JAVA_HOME before calling mvn. Seems, that you have java7 as default.